# Transcribe and the Pages module

Tags: multi-language, pages, transcribe

I've discovered that Transcribe doesn't fully support the Pages module, which means that certain things don't work properly. For example the Transcribe language switcher will redirect to the homepage instead of the linked Pages entry.

```
{exp:transcribe:language_links}
```

It looks like to fix to the language switcher would require changes to

```
function  _uri_reverse_lookup()
```

Anyone done this already or able to help?